# What alternatives do we have for Google's reCaptcha?

Tags: privacy, captcha

reCaptcha has been getting some criticism over that it's tracking visitor data recently. What are the best solutions available? Is there one that has better privacy for visitors?

Comment: "alternative to reCaptcha" is not a problem description. You need to describe what kind of security problem you want to solve and within what constraints. If the only problem is privacy then simply don't use reCaptcha. If you employ reCaptcha to solve a specific problem then please describe this problem too since the alternative should obviously fit the problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The use of CAPTCHA is singular and is contained in its name: Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart

Comment: Recapcha is one of the best captchas, mainly because it rarely requires users to perform any actual tasks. There are a lot of old-school picture-based capcha systems, just google for "captcha sources"

Comment: @AndrewMorozko: what you describe is a very abstract problem description and not an actual use case. There is a reason someone wants to keep computers and humans apart, like anti-spam protection for comments, prevention of screen scraping ... . And there are different qualities of protection and usability needed in the specific use case, i.e. depending on what you need to protect, what other protections you have, what abilities  your can expect from your users, what abilities you can expect from your enemies etc.

Comment: @AndrewMorozko: In other words:  If you want to have something which does exactly the same as reCaptcha then you need reCaptcha. If you want to have something different then you need to describe the requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own captcha. How well that works depends on how much work you put into it. You could, for example, create an image with a sum:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 72 'label:7+8=' label.gif
```

and expect the user to solve the sum. Note: 7 and 8 should of course be replaced by random numbers and the output filename would also depend on your web application. That will weed out all the simple robots. You can blur, add noise to the image, put other things in it et cetera.

If you make that more complicated (multiple images, which image contains an object, random style captcha etc.) you will be a bit more secure.

No need for Google's captcha, depending a bit on the rest of your service.

If you roll your own captcha, you should monitor its use. If it is solved multiple times per second from a single IP address (to state the obvious), you might consider making it more difficult.

Comment: Many modern spambots have plugins to automatically solve trivial captchas with OCR and analyze them to see if they should be input literally, or need to be "solved". The plugins have basic mathematics capabilities and huge lists of answers to common trivia questions. You'd need to make it a _bit_ more complex.

Comment: And to add to the comment from forest: most trivial captchas like this are harder to solve for the human than for the machine.

Comment: As I said, this will weed-out the simple robots. Not all modern spambots.  And you should monitor its usage.